# How should I fix the misspelled error for CRAN submission?

Tags: cran

After submitting my package into CRAN, I got below message which is a NOTE:

```
    New submission

Package was archived on CRAN

Possibly misspelled words in DESCRIPTION:
  Efron (15:5)
  Gu (16:5)
  Korotkevich (14:5)
  Ritchie (11:5)
  al (11:16, 12:13, 13:17, 14:20, 15:14)
  et (11:13, 12:10, 13:14, 14:17, 15:11)

CRAN repository db overrides:
  X-CRAN-Comment: Archived on 2023-05-25 as issues were not corrected
    in time.

  Not using suggested packages conditionally.
```

All of the authors are correct. The DESCRIPTION file is like :

```
Ritchie et al. (2015) <doi:10.1093/nar/gkv007>.
    Love et al. (2014) <doi:10.1186/s13059-014-0550-8>.
    Robinson et al. (2010) <doi:10.1093/bioinformatics/btp616>.
    Korotkevich et al. (2016) <arxiv:10.1101/060012>.
    Efron et al. (2015) <https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=GSA>.
    Gu, Z. (2012) <https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=CePa>.
```

I am not sure though what is the problem? The package is rejected for this single NOTE.

Comment: But apostrophes around all of them.  'Efron', 'Gu', ... Or, because this is corny, reword and just reference the doi links.